# How to delete a tableView row in VC 1 from a modalVC?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, row

I am using coreData and simply sending data from the tableView cell content that is text and the color of the cell to a modal view controller. In modalVC, I am able to change the text and when I press done, the tableView gets updated. 
Now I want to add a feature in which if the text is removed completely and the user press done, the data from coreData should be deleted and so should the tableView row.

Here is what I am doing in order to achieve this:

```
@IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: Any) {
if edittasktextview.text.isEmpty == true 
{
moContext.delete(editnotes[num] as NSManagedObject)
        editnotes.remove(at: num)
}
else 
{
editnotes[num].sNote = edittasktextview.text
}
}
```

num is the indexPath which I am sending from the first VC to modal VC (kind of keeping track of which cell is tapped)

Now when I dismiss the modal viewcontroller, a notification is send to the firstVC to trigger a func which essentially reloads the tableView in firstVC. However, while the row is no longer seen in the tableview, I still have have to go back to my rootVC and then back to first VC to update the tableView completely.

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a `NSFetchedResultsController` in firstVC?

Comment: nope! how should i use it?

Comment: @meaning-matters I am using NSFetchRequest to fetch coreData stuff and display it in tableview

Answer (score 0):

Use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to let your table view be triggered by CoreData changes.

[Here's a tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) to get you started. There are various other good tutorials and YT videos that are easy to find.

Comment: Basically NSFetchedResultsController acts as a replacement for the array?